# Overlapping dates across many groups with max of one status and min of other status

Tags: sql, date, sql-date-functions

I need to get maximum overlapping range for status A and minimum overlapping range for status B  . So if  a date is in active status in any of the records, it should be counted towards Active date range in output. I need to get final range of active and B (a date will be counted towards B only if none of the records has A status for that date). Please see below sample example for details:

For ex :

```
Start_Date  End_Date Record_Type
1/2/18      4/22/18 A
4/23/18 12/28/18    B
12/29/18    7/24/19 A
7/25/19 3/12/20 B
3/13/20 4/7/21      B
4/8/21      12/31/99    A
1/1/19      3/2/19      A
3/3/19      7/22/19 B
7/23/19 4/2/20      A
4/3/20      5/16/21 B
6/16/21 12/31/99    A
1/1/16      2/7/17      A
2/8/17      3/3/18      B
3/4/18      2/7/21      A
2/8/21      12/31/99    B
```

Expected Output :

```
1/1/16      2/7/17      A
2/8/17      1/1/18      B
1/2/18      2/7/21      A
2/8/21      4/7/21      B
4/8/21      12/31/99    A
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find the inflection points for every change to your value, but in looking at your expected results, could you explain why the `4/23/18 12/28/18    B` range isn't in your result set?  That period of time appears to be represented here `1/2/18      2/7/21      A` but wouldn't you want to capture that range as B in your results??

Comment: Last I checked Snowflake is not SQL Server - please ensure you tag only the relevant RDBMS.

Comment: And please show us what you have tried so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: @MikeWalton A status takes preference. So for a date range if any of the group has A status, that date will be included in A. And only the date where none of the group has A status will be included in Date range for B. In this example group 3 has A record for 3/4/18 to 2/7/21 ( which covers 4/23/18 to 12/28/18 as well) so this is why this date is not recoded for B status. In result set I just need one continuous date range, no overlapping dates ( so on any date it can be either A or B not both).

Comment: (1) I removed the inconsistent database tags.  (2) I just don't follow what you are doing.  SQL starts with *tables* and *columns*.  That the "three groups" separate tables?  An explanation would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the question . Hopefully its more clear now.